# MinGW add Asio standalone library

Tags: c++, mingw, boost-asio

i want to use Asio standalone library for networking in my c++ project, but i'm having issues with my compiler/linker (MinGW).
I put the "include" folder in the "asio-1.18.1" folder in the "include" folder of MinGW and renamed it to Asio, but it doesn't work.

I also tried to use the "LIBRARY_PATH" environement variable, but with no luck either.

I used the -L flag too but nothing so far.
Hope you can solve my issue.

Comment: Can you explain what issues you have (which compiler and/or linker errors)?
Did you actually build asio-1.18.1 ?

Comment: my issue is that my linker is not finding the header files i include.
I didn't build it since it is a header based library.

Comment: linkers don't look for header files, that's a compiler's job. please post the actual output as "having issues" is too vague for people to be able to help you.